# Abelian group in short exact sequence

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

If we have a short exact sequence of continuous group homomorphisms between abelian groups
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow X \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0,$$
can we conclude that $X = \mathbb{Z}^3$? I want to say, since the map $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow X$ is injective by exactness, that its image is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and then just use the first isomorphism theorem; however, is that necessarily true and if so how would I be rigorous about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This as an exact sequence of abelian groups, or $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, so it is split since the third term $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [projective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module#Split-exact_sequences) $\mathbb{Z}$-module. By the [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma), it follows $X\cong (\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.